# Onpress is launched automatically

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Hello I have this Lisview and on the renderRow I have this return statement :

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={this._onPressWidget(rowData)}>
        <View>
        <View style={style}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>
              {rowData}
            </Text>
        </View>
     </View>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

The thing is that the onPress function is launched automatically without pressing the button. Can anyone tell me why is that? I'm doing this with react native

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling the `_onPressWidget` during rendering. What you need to do is pass a callback function that calls it, once the callback executes.

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this._onPressWidget(rowData)}>
```

Answer (score 0):

seriously save my hours!! thx a lot.
I should share the tips here:

```
    let returnView = this.props.item.map((v,i ) => {


    return <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this._fireEventToParent(v.id)}>
             <View style={ListItemStyles.liPiece}>
                  <Image style={[ListItemStyles.liPieceImage} source={{uri: v.itemImage }} />
                  <Text style={ListItemStyles.liPieceTxt}>{v.itemName}</Text>
             </View>
         </TouchableHighlight>;

});
```

only map can work here, I tried forEach, cannot work.